# Vectorized linear regression

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra, linear-regression

Here is my attempt to perform linear regression utilizing just numpy and linear algebra :

```
def linear_function(w , x , b):
    return np.dot(w , x) + b

x = np.array([[1, 1,1],[0, 0,0]])
y = np.array([0,1])

w = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(1 , 3))

print(w)
learning_rate = .0001

xT = x.T
yT = y.T

for i in range(30000):

    h_of_x = linear_function(w , xT , 1)
    loss = h_of_x - yT

    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print(loss , w)
    w = w + np.multiply(-learning_rate , loss)

linear_function(w , x , 1)
```

This causes an error :

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-137-130a39956c7f> in <module>()
     24     if i % 10000 == 0:
     25         print(loss , w)
---> 26     w = w + np.multiply(-learning_rate , loss)
     27 
     28 linear_function(w , x , 1)

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (1,3) (1,2)
```

This appears to work for reduced training set dimensionality :

```
import numpy as np

def linear_function(w , x , b):
    return np.dot(w , x) + b

x = np.array([[1, 1],[0, 0]])
y = np.array([0,1])

w = np.random.uniform(-1,1,(1 , 2))

print(w)
learning_rate = .0001

xT = x.T
yT = y.T

for i in range(30000):

    h_of_x = linear_function(w , xT , 1)
    loss = h_of_x - yT

    if i % 10000 == 0:
        print(loss , w)
    w = w + np.multiply(-learning_rate , loss)

linear_function(w , x , 1)

print(linear_function(w , x[0] , 1))
print(linear_function(w , x[1] , 1))
```

Which returns :

```
[[ 0.68255806 -0.49717912]]
[[ 1.18537894  0.        ]] [[ 0.68255806 -0.49717912]]
[[ 0.43605474  0.        ]] [[-0.06676614 -0.49717912]]
[[ 0.16040755  0.        ]] [[-0.34241333 -0.49717912]]
[ 0.05900769]
[ 1.]
```

`[ 0.05900769] & [ 1.]` are close to the training examples so appears this implementation is correct. What is issue with implementation that is throwing error ? I have not implemented the extension of dimensionality from 2 -> 3 correctly ?

Comment: You got any data to work with here?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ the data is defined in the x and y variables

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've outlined the issues below:

1. your array shapes are inconsistent. This could result in issues with broadcasting/dots, especially during gradient descent. Fix your initialisation. I would also recommend augmenting `w` with `b` and `X` with a column of ones.
2. your loss function and gradient calculation don't seem right to me. In general, using manhattan distance as a loss function is not recommended as it is not a sufficient distance metric. I would go with Euclidean distance and attempt to minimise the sum of squares (this is called [OLS regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares)). We then proceed with the gradient calculation as follows.
3. your update rule will change accordingly based on (2).
4. make sure to instate a stopping condition for your code. You don't want to overshoot the optimum. Usually, you should stop when the gradient does not change much.

Full listing:

```
# input, augmented
x = np.array([[1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0]])
x = np.column_stack((np.ones(len(x)), x))
# predictions
y = np.array([[0, 1]])   
# weights, augmented with bias
w = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, (1, 4))

learning_rate = .0001

loss_old = np.inf
for i in range(30000):  
    h_of_x = w.dot(x.T)
    loss = ((h_of_x - y) ** 2).sum()

    if abs(loss_old - loss) < 1e-5:
        break

    w = w - learning_rate * (h_of_x - y).dot(x)
    loss_old = loss
```

---

**Other Recommendations/Enhancements**

Next, consider the use of regularisation here. L1 (ridge) and L2 (lasso) are both good alternatives.

Finally, there is a closed form solution for Linear Regression that is guaranteed to converge at a local optimum (gradient descent does only guarantee a *local* optimum). This is fast, but computationally expensive (since it involves calculating an inverse). See the tradeoffs [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/278755/why-use-gradient-descent-for-linear-regression-when-a-closed-form-math-solution/308356).

```
w = y.dot(np.linalg.inv(x.dot(x.T)).dot(x))
```

When xT.x is not invertible, you will need to regularise.

Keep in mind that Linear Regression can only model *linear* decision boundaries. If you're convinced your implementation is correct, and that your loss is still bad, your data may not be fittable in its current vector-space, so you will need non-linear basis function to transform it (this is effectively non-linear regression).

Comment: @coldspeed thanks, in order to make prediction of existing training data is this correct ? : print(w.dot(x[0].T))
print(w.dot(x[1].T))

Comment: @blue-sky yes, `w.dot(x.T)` will do the same thing giving you an array of predictions, one prediction for each row in x.

Comment: @coldspeed my dataset is linearly separable so print(w.dot(x.T)) should return values close to [0 , 1] but instead returns [[ 0.02126646  0.        ]] ?

Comment: @blue-sky oops, I forgot that your bias is not being updated as well. Give me a second.

Comment: @blue-sky There we go. Take a look now, works flawlessly. I've also added a closed form solution at the bottom.

Comment: @coldspeed defining the y variables as y = np.array([[1],[0]]) instead of y = np.array([[0, 1]])   also works